# How write js code for shows 6 div per slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need code in jQuery to show 6 div's per slide. I have slider, and I want show only 6 div's/elements and after 6 div the code will be create next slide(div with class slide)

`<div class="slide">
    <div>
     6elements
    </div>
</div>
next slide  => <div> 6 elements </div>`

Comment: Could you make a complete code snippet or jsfiddle of your current code?

Comment: post has been edited

Comment: What kind of slider are you using? Do you have a link?

Comment: http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Slick slider

Here is a **[working Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/UaBKU843yB8fIOTCwjj0?p=preview)** that shows how to implement the jQuery/Slick plugin with responsive break points.

The documentation for [Slick](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) provides several options for your slides.

#### Javascript

```
$('#slick').slick({
    infinite: true,
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    rows: 2,
    slidesPerRow: 3,
    responsive: [{
        breakpoint: 600,
        settings: {
            slidesToShow: 1,
            rows: 2,
            slidesPerRow: 2,
        }
    }]
});
```

#### HTML

```
<div id="slick">
    <div class="slide">
        <div class="img-container"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/alhBkw5.png"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
        <div class="img-container"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/Qdqaawt.png"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
        <div class="img-container"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/Bplxu8k.jpg"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
        <div class="img-container"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/fixuYTj.jpg"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
        <div class="img-container"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/IhOP2Sh.jpg"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
        <div class="img-container"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/9hpqKt0.jpg"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
        <div class="img-container"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/IhOP2Sh.jpg"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
        <div class="img-container"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/9VCx5.jpg"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
        <div class="img-container"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/scV4kAY.png"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
        <div class="img-container"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/PfDrZOZ.jpg"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
        <div class="img-container"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/lxMUSqZ.jpg"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
        <div class="img-container"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/wD1r3Yk.png"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
.img-container {
    overflow: hidden;
    max-height: 100px;
    margin: 3px 5px;
}
.img-container img {
    width: 100%;
}
#slick {
    /* optional */
    max-width: 700px;
    margin: 50px auto;
}
```

## Wordpress Function

Here is a **[Wordpress demo](http://wordpress.adriancarriger.com/stack-overflow-example-33925475/)** of the following php function.

#### PHP

Add this function to your `functions.php` file:

```
function six_images_slider() {
    $args = array('numberposts' => 18);
    $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );
    $output = '<div id="slick">';
    foreach ($recent_posts as $post) {
        $featured_image_src = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post['ID'] ) );
        $output .= '<div class="slide"><div class="img-container"><img src="'.$featured_image_src.'"></div></div>';
    }
    $output .= '</div>';
    echo $output;
}
```

Add this to your `home.php` template file:

```
<?php six_images_slider(); ?>
```

Also, it should work in any Wordpress template file.

**Function Explanation**

- This function gets the most recent 18 posts by calling [wp_get_recent_posts](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_recent_posts).
- Then it loops through the posts and gets the featured image by calling [get_post_thumbnail_id](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_thumbnail_id) and passing the result to [wp_get_attachment_url](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_url) to get the src.

Comment: I think it isnt working like I want. Because as I said I want this in to column and script must add div automatically after 6 elements

Comment: Can you draw a picture of how it should look?

Comment: @pankrystek Thanks for the picture! It now looks similar. Let me know if this is what you mean by _"automatically after 6 elements"_.

Comment: this is not automatically, it is manual, I want show 6 post in 2 colums per slide in wordpress... but with this I added myself slides with 6 elements ? Are you understand my question ?

Comment: Are you wanting to have this display your latest Wordpress posts starting with the most recent? What file are you editing in Wordpress? Is it your `home.php` page?

Comment: In this slide i want to show my last 18 posts, but it should be dispaly in 3 slides. Yes I edit home page

Comment: Should clicking on a picture take you to that post?

Comment: Yep, but i need only js script to add div with class slide after show 6 posts, why u ask about function my picrutes ?

Comment: It sounds like you'll need a php function that you add to `functions.php` that pulls the images from your Wordpress database. Then you can just insert that function into your `home.php` and it will setup the slides. This will automatically show 6 `div` elements per slide. It sounds like clicking on an image should take you to the post for that image too.

Comment: No problem, happy to help!

Comment: I had to change several things to show 4 per slide on mobile, but the answer turned out to be simpler overall. Let me know how it works. Thanks!

Comment: It doesnt work, but nvm for this. Because I have problem, how do this in wordpress, team showcase in slide ? -http://i.imgur.com/RSKwpja.jpg.

Comment: It's working on my end. Did the demo and Plunker work correctly for you? Also, if you have a new question, post it on Stackoverflow and send me the link in a comment. Thanks!

Comment: You should be able to put `get_post_meta ( $post['ID'], 'your-key-here');` in the PHP to access your custom field (just put your actual key in the code and it should work). Here's the [Wordpress Docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/) on `get_post_meta`.

Comment: adriancarriger - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34123785/how-create-custom-navigation-for-slick-slider-to-wordpress ;>